# Save email attachment as .html file

Tags: html, email, attachment, power-automate

I receive automated emails with HTML attachments. For some reason, the extension of the attachment is .EXCEL. I can't control that. If I save it to my desktop and rename it to have a .html extension, it loads as it should. Using Power Automate, I want to change the extension and save the file to SharePoint. How can I do that?

If it wasn't for needing to change the extension, I would know how to handle this. Setting the filename to use a .html extension in the "Create file" action using the content of the email attachment doesn't work. The file content is garbled code instead of the HTML code.

Here's how I'm creating the file in SharePoint based on the file content of the attachment.
[image]

Comment: Can you share how you're grabbing the attachments from the message in Power Automate? Which action are you leveraging?

Comment: @esqew I added a screenshot and additional information. I'm getting the File Content on the email attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Attachments Content is empty within the Attachments list. You will need to do a `Get Attachments (V2)` action to get the contents.
[image]